# The font-color does not change in editing and in output (DecoupledEditor)

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Why does changing the font color in the DecoupledEditor editor not work? What could be this error?

```
<p> </p><p><span class="text-big" style="color:hsl(0,100%,38%);"><strong>Handheld emperor</strong>
```

[image]

I have such an entry in my styles. Can it affect I/O? If so, then a lot of which nodes can affect the formatting. What should I do in this case? Must I Search for them all by project and rename them, or is there some other solution?

```
strong, b {
    color: #3c3b3b;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

I removed color: #3c3b3b; in this style and the color appeared, but when I set this  tag  it turns back to black. Italics also don't work at all.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Italics worked - it was necessary to remove the i tag in styles. But the problem with strong + bold remained.